# How can I toast chocolate chip bread?

Tags: food, temperature

I bought a beautiful loaf of chocolate chip brioche and I want to toast it:

[image: Chocolate Chip Brioche]

But when I toast it, the chocolate chips melt into my toaster. How can I fix this?

Comment: @RedSonja If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can toast bread in a flat frying pan on a stove top. Be sure to flip the bread to toast both sides. Some of the chocolate may melt out, but you should be able to scrape it off of the pan with a spatula and "reapply" it to your toast.

Answer (score 4):

Place the bread on a heat-resistant surface and use a paint stripper (heat gun) (or a gas torch, if you're adventurous) to toast the bread.

Answer (score 2):

You could obtain 'toastie bags'. These are made for making cheese toasties in toasters, place a slice in a bag and then pop them into your toaster.

and example can be found [here](http://www.thesafetysupplycompany.co.uk/p/9154774/sealapack---re-usable-toaster-bags---pack-of-2---af-5050375089938.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIxtCeiJLo1gIVzLDtCh237AufEAQYBCABEgLioPD_BwE). But please feel free to find your own if you decide to purchase.

Comment: I actually have these and I thought about using them but then I'm just making mess in the bags. I guess that's slightly better.

Answer (score 1):

You can pre heat the oven to around 170 degrees then put the slices off brioche in the oven, on a baking tray, for around 5 minutes. Works a treat!

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

It seems obvious you can't toast bread with chocolate on the outside. If it has to be warm, then pop it on a plate and zap it in the microwave.

But then it isn't toasted and that is not a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the bread in a metallic mesh (such as a fish grill) above a gas or electric ring turning often, browning as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I'd cut myself a thick slice, pick the visible surface chocolate chips out and eat them (or save them) then toast the result

Answer (score -2):

You can try placing a pan over a vessel of boiling water and put choc chip bread so as to toast it without melting the choc chip due to excessive heat. Hope this helps!

Comment: That would just leave a soggy mess. 100° is not hot enough to burn the edges of the bread.

Comment: And the choc chips will melt at well below 100 °C.